# Confused about a limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{2x}$$

EDIT: Thank you for your answers and suggestions, I am sorry I didn't use MathJax from the beginning.

But if I may ask, why this doesn't led to the solution?:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\cdot\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\cdot2x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\cdot2x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}\cdot2x}=e^{0/\infty}=e^0=1$$
I used Euler's number: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e \ , \ where \ n=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}{x-\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}$$

Comment: write your formula here please!

Comment: ... and use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is attracting downvotes and votes to close instead of answers because you've made it much too hard for anyone here to help you. If you edit the question to include the actual text (not a picture) and explain where you think your error might possibly be in "the second way" maybe someone will take a look. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've added the exponent 2x which appears on your work

Comment: You were going in the right direction covering the hard part of the question and then for the simpler part you made the wrong move. The limit of the exponent $(x-\sqrt{\dots}) \cdot 2x/\sqrt {\dots} $ is evaluated by multiplying numerator and denominator with conjugate $x+\sqrt{\dots} $. After thus you can easily see the exponent tends to $-2$ and the answer is $1/e^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so frustrated that I couldn't understand what I did wrong and you saved my day! I guess math can be very tricky.

Comment: You are not supposed to get frustrated while doing math. You are supposed to enjoy it (that's the secret to math which no one believes btw):) :)

Comment: The question is now in good shape. Still some close votes coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{2x}=e^{2x\log\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)}=e^{-2x\log\left( \sqrt{1+\frac2x+\frac2{x^2}} \right)}=e^{-x \log\left( 1+\frac2x+\frac2{x^2} \right)}$$

then use infinitesimal expansion for $y\to 0 \implies \log (1+y) \sim y$ for

$$\log\left( 1+\frac2x+\frac2{x^2} \right)\sim \frac2x+\frac2{x^2}$$

You can fix your work as follow

$$...=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}\cdot2x}=e^{-2}$$

indeed

$$\frac{x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}\cdot2x=\frac{x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}\cdot2 \to -2$$

since

$$x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}\sim x-x-1-\frac1x\to-1$$

in the last we have used binomial expansion for $y\to 0 \implies (1+y)^n=1+ny$.

Comment: Thank you! A final question: what did I do wrong in my example?

Comment: @MathNoob It seems that in the final step you have an indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$

Comment: @MathNoob I've added the way you can conclude by your work!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort you put in order to make me trying to understand. I am sorry if I am too dumb but can you explain a little more in depth why is $$x-x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}\ \ \ \sim\ x-x-1-\frac{1}{x}$$ my stupid brain thinks it should be $$x-x\cdot\sqrt{1}=x-x=0$$ and I kinda don't really get it with the binomaial expansion. Thank you!

Comment: @MathNoob in this way you are neglecting the contribution of the $\frac1x$ term, if you don't like binomial expansion, let try to derive it by multipling by $$\frac{ x+x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} }{x+x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} }$$

Comment: Oooh, I get it now! I was going to the limit, while still $$using \ x \ instead \ of \infty$$ , which would give an indeterminate form $$\infty \ -\infty$$ Now I truly understand it! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}}\right)^{2x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+2x+2}\right)^x$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x^2+2x+2}{x^2}\right)^{-x}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{2x+2}{x^2}\right)^{x^2/(2x+2)}\right)^{-\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2x+2}x}$$

The inner limit converges to $e$

Can you handle the limit in the exponent?

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem in this way, the final result being $$\frac{1}{e^2}.$$ But I was wondering why in my example (without raising  the fraction to the power of 2) , didn't get me the same answer.